# Flutter share_plus IOS errors

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, share-plus

I am using Share_plus flutter extension to use the inbuilt share dialogue. I am testing using an iPhone 6. The function works perfectly on android.

Here is my function to show the dialogue in a separate class Called InviteFriends

```
Future<void> shareEventDialogue(String eventUrl, BuildContext context) async {
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    await Share.share("Join my SHOTS event: $eventUrl",
        sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
  }
```

This is Called by `InviteFriends().shareEventDialogue(eventUrl,context);`

My error is as follows

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, sharePositionOrigin: argument must be set, {{0, 0}, {375, 670.31500000000005}} must be non-zero and within coordinate space of source view: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      InvitingFriends.shareEventDialogue (package:shots/events/detailsComponents/inviting_links.dart:32:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      EventDetailsScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:shots/events/details_screen.dart:471:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

This should've been fixed by the 'sharePosition...' attribute. I think I've followed the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) properly. I may have missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when you remove `sharePositionOrigin`? If so, then you can make a check if the host device is an iPhone or iPad (docs said the parameter is required to fix error in iPad), for example by combining Platform.isIOS and some kind of screen size check

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering around I found setting clear bounds works.

```
sharePositionOrigin: Rect.fromPoints(const Offset(0, 0), const Offset(1, 1)
```